# “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)” option not working

Tags: publishing, cme, bundles

**Scenario:**

I have a bundle which has 4 pages, A,B,C and D. Out of these pages 2 are published (A and B) and 2 are new pages (not published any where). The bundle is being published to single `target type` associated with only one `publication target`. 
When I select the bundle for publish, “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)” option is selected and if I click "Show Items To Publish", I see Page A and B in the list of items to be published from the bundle which is a correct behavior.

**Question:**

Now, if I **un-select** the “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)” option and subsequently click/check the "Show Items To Publish", the list is **not getting updated** and is still showing Page A and B. It does not include Page C and D which should have been included in "Show Items To Publish" since I had un-selected the “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)”option. The **Show Items to Publish** list is not getting updated on **select/un-select** of “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)” option no matter how many times I select or un-select the checkbox

If only I select a different `target type` and then click on "Show Items To Publish" the list gets updated and shows Page A,B,C and D. 
Is anybody else facing the same issue with “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)” option? Or is this a known issue? Is there a hotfix I am missing for this specific functionality?

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1. I have tested on all the browsers and see the same issue.

**Edit 1:**

I validated the publishes and it is working as expected and includes the Pages A,B,C and D. The problematic part seems to be the GUI since it is not showing the correct details and makes you think that the pages are not going to be part of the publish even when you uncheck the option. The only way to figure out what is published, is by opening the transaction details and finding list of items processed! I am planning to open a ticket with Tridion since it seems a bug

**Edit 2:**

I have raised a ticket with Tridion Support for the same. Alternatively, there are three possible ways of refreshing the list:

1. As suggested by Alvin, using the "Refresh" button after select/unselect on “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)” will refresh the list of items to be published
2. Click on "Hide Items To Publish" and then "Show Items To Publish" button after select/unselect on “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)”. This also refreshes the list of items to be published
3. Change the target type or unselect and select the target type after select/unselect on “Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)” will also refresh the list of items to be published

Comment: Did you check if pages C and D are being published as expected when you uncheck "Republish Only"? It would be helpful to know if it's just an issue with the GUI or if the underlying functionality is affected as well.

Comment: Updated the question to include the details

Comment: At least in Chrome and Firefox, toggling the *Show Items* or pressing the *Refresh* button at the bottom of the Show Items to Publish list seem to both update the list of pages in a Bundle correctly (Tridion 2013 SP1 setup, 7.1.0.66). Try the *Refresh* button but definitely run this by Support, maybe also checking for what the browser Console reports.

Comment: Have you installed HR1?

Comment: @PeterKjaer no we haven't installed HR1

Comment: @AlvinReyes I have raised a ticket with Tridion support and following up on that. So, far what I have heard back is: "uncheck/check" the option and then click on "hide items to publish" and then "show items to publish" to refresh the list. This means 2 additional clicks after selecting/un-selecting the option. From a user perspective, it is definitely not an ideal usage scenario since the select/un-select operation was already done. I will update my question once I receive more feedback from support or if I get a resolution, I will update with an answer.

Comment: @AlvinReyes I just tried the refresh option after select/un-select and it did updated the list. It is definitely not intuitive (our users are confused with the way it is working now)

Comment: I can see that. Would it be easier if the buttons stayed at the top? And maybe the refresh should only appear after showing the list the first time. After showing the list, does it make sense to let users hide it?

Comment: If the button stayed on top, may be that will be more helpful. Also, enabling refresh button after first list retrieval may also be helpful indicator that now the user also needs to refresh everytime. That being said, having been in the technology world for a long time, I feel technology can be better leveraged here and another AJAX call should be used to fetch the list on action (check/uncheck). I do not foresee performance concerns as this is only on publish. Well, we ventured into usability analysis here, but I believe it is in the interest of the product and its usage :)